# Control TPTP profiling programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse, profiling, eclipse-tptp

I need to profile a server-client Java application (based on Jersey/REST FYI).

I have learned around that profiling remote servers is a real pain with TPTP, so I want to keep it simple :
I have written a test case (a "main") that runs a standalone server (Grizzly) and a client (within a separate thread) and process some load tests.

I can run it in profiling mode (with Eclipse/TPTP), but I would like to isolate my core methods from all the noise of the server and client setup.

I there a mean to programmatically enable / disable the TPTP profiling in my code, at some check points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) for profiling your app, irrespective if you're using it for development.   It can filter by package, class, or method so you only see what you want, as well as having nifty [profiling points](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/profiler-profilingpoints.html) (things like stopwatches but way more powerful).  You can do things like:

[image]
[image]

Sorry for all the screenshots, but IMHO they help people who have never profiled before and are wondering what it can do for them.